# Words with letter and numbers that can contain dashes and swedish characters

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regexp which validates against all english letters + the swedish "åäö (lower and uppercase)". Also, the word can contain 1 or more "-" and can be of any length.

`^[a-zA-Z\dåäöÅÄÖ\-*]*$`

Is this correct? Can it be improved? If I recall correctly, `a-zA-Z` icludes more than just those letters (some characters in the ascii table between a-z and A-Z).

http://regexr.com?36svf

Update: Here are the characters that I'm refering to:

Update 2: I also want to include digits.

[image]

Comment: When asking regex questions, it is important to also specify the programming language or tool you're working with, because different regex implementations do have different features. Some regex variants may need a `u` modifier to trigger UTF-8 character support.

Comment: You just need to make sure that this regex and the string to be matched have the same encoding.

Comment: There's also "é" in the Swedish language such as "idé".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is OK, but why are you including the asterisk (`*`)?

`[A-Za-z]` only matches ASCII letters, it's `[A-z]` that's problematic because there are some special characters between `Z` and `a`.

So `^[a-zA-Z\dåäöÅÄÖ-]*$` should be OK.

Comment: Right, thank you. Forgot to mention that I want digits as well. My bad!

Comment: To answer about `*`, because I want to match 0 or more `-`. But I guess it's reduntant?

Comment: The "outer" `*` already does that. The `*` inside the character class is treated like a literal, so your regex would also match the string `"***"`.